# Deep linking with JIRA

Tags: azure-devops

In this demo just released (https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-Pipelines-multi-cloud-support-and-integration-with-DevOps-tools) they show that you can deep link with JIRA but give no links on how to do this. We are currently looking to use Azure DevOps, but have no plans to use the Boards feature right now because of how deep we are into JIRA. Does anyone have any idea how they linked to JIRA as shown in this demo?

Comment: It uses Jenkins do do that trick it seems.

Comment: It's a feature of the `JenkinsDownloadArtifacts` task.